# How to perform MANOVA with categorical independent variables

Tags: anova, python, manova, statsmodels

I have a dataset where the independent variable is sieve size (categorically either 25, 63, 100 or 150), and the dependent variables are length and width.

```py
>>> print(total.loc[::20])
>>>  Length     Width       seive
0    242.47293  14.91069     25
20    57.19134   7.80266     25
46   175.70300  14.18000     25
68   156.72451  14.80177     25
93    51.86538  13.66030     25
116   69.32484   7.89510     25
136  288.29452  15.44413     25
168  440.32766  14.38040     25
188  220.48884  13.88941     25
217  251.99140  14.92267     25
241  286.75198  15.68166     25
261  296.63282  15.66844     25
22   276.33100  12.91300     63
46   268.02600  14.39900     63
68   543.82800  13.10900     63
92   329.51000  14.32200     63
115  270.72000  15.63500     63
6    316.07000  13.81000    100
27   374.80100  17.26000    100
54   456.59900  13.90800    100
78   677.59700  15.11400    100
18   459.73900  15.46300    150
```

I want to check if the mean values of length and width are statistically significant between sieve sizes. To do this i believe i need to perform a MANOVA test (p < 0.05 if significant) (please correct me if i'm wrong).

The doccumentation on [statsmodels MANOVA function](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.multivariate.manova.MANOVA.html) is very short and i can't find any examples in it.

How should I perform the MANOVA test with statsmodels or is there another library/test better suited to this purpose?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `manova()` function.

With your data, the following can do what you ask.

`response<- cbind(total.loc$Length, total.loc$Width)`

The final model can be specified as:

```
My_Model <- manova(response~ seive, data=total.loc)
```

*seive* should be a factor variable

The `summary` function will provide the MANOVA output.

```
summary(My_Model , intercept=TRUE)
```

**Note that** by default, the only root statistics presented is the Pillai’s trace.

To obtain the results for the other root statistics, you just have to specify the name of the test.

For example, the results for Wilk's Lambda can be specified as:

```
summary(My_Model , intercept=TRUE, test="Wilks")
```

There are also several web references

http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/manova-test-in-r-multivariate-analysis-of-variance
https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/one-way-manova-in-r/
https://gaopinghuang0.github.io/2017/11/20/MANOVA-notes-and-R-code